# DJango not excuting Javascript loaded from a file

Tags: javascript, django, static

I'm learning by examples and tried a code by @furins.  The code works when the button is clicked, it calls the javascript function.  But when I separate the javascript into a separate file static/js/test.js, it doesn't do anything. http://localhost:8080/static/js/test.js shows the script text, so static directory is working.  What am I missing?

```
*** original ***
<html>
<head>
    <title>An example</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function call_counter(url, pk) {
            window.open(url);
            $.get('YOUR_VIEW_HERE/'+pk+'/', function (data) {
                alert("counter updated!");
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="call_counter('http://www.google.com', 12345);">
        I update object 12345
    </button>
    <button onclick="call_counter('http://www.yahoo.com', 999);">
        I update object 999
    </button>
</body>
```

Separated:

```
*** base.html ***
{% load static %}
<html>
<head>
    <title>An example</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'js/test.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="call_counter('http://www.google.com', 12345);">
        I update object 12345
    </button>
    <button onclick="call_counter('http://www.yahoo.com', 999);">
        I update object 999
    </button>
</body>
```

```
*** static/js/test.js ***
function call_counter(url, pk) {
    window.open(url);
    $.get('YOUR_VIEW_HERE/'+pk+'/', function (data) {
        alert("counter updated!");
    });
}
```

Comment: If you check the site source, do you see the correct URL? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: what is the static url and static root in setting.py

Comment: @KonradLinkowski No error on console.  I put an image with <img src="{% static 'image/logo.png'"></img> and the image shows fine.  http://localhost:8080/static/js/test.js displays the script, so isn't the URL correct?

Comment: @HarshGupta STATIC_URL = 'static/' but I don't have STATIC_ROOT.  http://localhost:8080/static/js/test.js shows the script, so isn't the path correct?  Seems it's finding the script but just not executing the script.

Comment: You should check network tab in chrome if the script loads. Execution of the script is unrelated to django.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski in the network tab, it shows jquery.min.js and test.js when opening the page.  When the button is pressed, but nothing changed when the button is pressed.  So the button is not working on click?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski No error.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I rebooted my system, and it's working now.  Must had a ghost in my system.  Thanks for your help.